# How do I avoid getting a NaN throughout a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My end goal: I want to upload a new table file (be it excel, pdf, txt, csv) to a master  excel spreadsheet. Then, pick out several columns from that master datasheet and then graph and group them by their state: are these samples falling under categories X or Y? And then plot them looking at each sample.

Datawise, I have samples that fall under X category or Y category. They are either X or Y, and have names associated with the samples as well as sample counts (e.g. sample #abc falls under category X and has 30 counts with different values).

I am using pandas to open the data and manipulate the tables. Here is the section of my code that is giving me issues. All other issues I have found workarounds. This one I cannot. I have tried doing fillna(df_choice.column) and I have found that it doesnt replace the NaN. Tried doing reset index or set index, doesnt really help. A sample output would have X (if I entered "X" first) or Y (if I entered "y" first) as NAN, yet the other three columns have no issues!

df_choice is a previous dataframe where I selected two columns from a master datasheet. In this case, it'd be columns X and Y.

```
df_new= {'X':[], 'Y':[], 'Property of X (units)':[], 'Property of Y (units)':[]} #setup dict
df_new= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_new) #dict to df

for df_choice.column in df_choice.columns: #list columns in previous dataset
    print(df_choice.column)
    state = input('Is this sample considered X or Y? Input X or Y, or quit to exit the loop') #ask if column in previous dataset falls under X or Y
    if state == 'quit':
        break
    elif state  == 'x':
        df_new['Property of X (units)'] = df_choice[df_choice.column] #takes data from old dataframe into new
        df_new['X'] = 'df_choice.column' #fills column X with column name from df_choice

    elif state == 'y':
        df_new['Y'] = 'df_choice.column'
        df_new['Property of Y (units)'] = df_choice[df_choice.column]
    else:
        print('Not a valid response')

df_new #prints new df
```

What I see (only showing 4 rows, but imagine every row as NaN):

```
+-----+------------+----------------+----------------+
|  X  |      Y     |  Property of X |  Property of Y |
+-----+------------+----------------+----------------+
| NaN |  Sample123 |              4 |              3 |
| NaN |  Sample123 |              5 |              4 |
| NaN |  Sample123 |              3 |              6 |
| NaN |  Sample123 |              4 |              1 |
+-----+------------+----------------+----------------+
```

What I should get:

```
+-----------+------------+----------------+----------------+
|     X     |      Y     |  Property of X |  Property of Y |
+-----------+------------+----------------+----------------+
| SampleABC |  Sample123 |              4 |              3 |
| SampleABC |  Sample123 |              5 |              4 |
| SampleABC |  Sample123 |              3 |              6 |
| SampleABC |  Sample123 |              4 |              1 |
+-----------+------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Eventually, I assume I'd want to df_new.melt() to eventually graph them, grouping bars or boxplots by X or Y,

```
+-----------+-------+-----------+
|  Sample   |  Type |  Property |
+-----------+-------+-----------+
| SampleABC |  X    |         4 |
| SampleABC |  X    |         5 |
| SampleABC |  X    |         3 |
| SampleABC |  X    |         4 |
| Sample123 |  Y    |         3 |
| Sample123 |  Y    |         4 |
| Sample123 |  Y    |         6 |
| Sample123 |  Y    |         1 |
+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

I am a month or so into self-taught coding, so I apologize if my code is inefficient or not very clever, I come across issues and look up how other people do them and see what works for me. No formal training and I am a material scientist by training. I don't know a whole lot and I figured the best way to learn is get some fundamentals down, and then make something genuinely useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the name of your column as a vector, rather than a single string when inserting into an empty dataframe.

Think about it this way: you're creating a column in an empty dataframe by passing a single string to it. But how can Pandas know what length the column should have?

The variable in your for-loop also has a bit confusing name:  the dot in "df_choice.column" looks as if you're accessing a dataframe.

Putting it together:

```
for colname in df_choice.columns:

    #...#
    elif state  == 'x':
        #takes data from old dataframe into new
        df_new['Property of X (units)'] = df_choice[colname] 

        #fills column X with column name from df_choice
        df_new['X'] = np.repeat(colname, df_choice.shape[0])

    elif state == 'y':
        df_new['Y'] = np.repeat(colname, df_choice.shape[0])
        df_new['Property of Y (units)'] = df_choice[colname]
```

Notice that I replaced the line for your "Y" variable as well, just in case it comes up before "X".

To use np.repeat import the library

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Hi, 
Do you mind explaining what this code does? Do I put this inside my for loop or do I take something out? 

From my guess, and please correct me if I am wrong, it looks like it is saying:
for values under Column X, return the column title of df_choice?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer. That line was intended to replace one line in your for-loop where you were inserting values for "X".

Comment: Woah! This....totally fixed it. Can you tell me exactly what this did, especially the shape[0] part? I know that shape command can tell you the size of your table, but not sure how this fixes my problem. Would you mind guessing as to why using a for loop with my method gave me NaN?